# How to write in Run command using python?

Tags: python, windows, text

How to make a program which can write the specific text in Run command using python?I need the code which can write automatically in Run command after i run the program like lets say i run the program which opens Run command and its automatically written there like for example cmd or visualstudio.Program is supposed to automatically open Run command and write the text in it automatically.

[image]

Comment: Please give me more detail of your problem :)

Comment: provide us with more details about your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pynput` module:

```py
import time

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

def main():
    keyboard = Controller()
    cmd = "cmd"

    keyboard.press(Key.cmd)
    keyboard.press('r')
    keyboard.release('r')
    keyboard.release(Key.cmd)

    # wait, until "Run Program Or File" window opens
    time.sleep(1) 

    for i in cmd:
        keyboard.press(i)
        keyboard.release(i)

    #keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    #keyboard.release(Key.enter)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Tested on Windows 7.